# New blockchain node get transactions

Tags: blockchain

When a new node gets created on a Blockchain does it receive a copy of all the old transaction blocks or only new transactions that arrive from that point onwards on the chain

Comment: may be you should ask such questions on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/  But most node software can be configured to run in either mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone tries to become a new node on a blockchain network,then he has to download the whole database of that blockchain network i.e. he will have the record of all the transactions from the genesis block till the current block.